# PHP files not executing

Tags: php, apache, configuration, vps, whm

I'm currently in the process of moving a Wordpress and Drupal website from a hostgator account to a VPS purchased by the client. The VPS has "WHM vps" installed.

I've had a whole lot of problems with this for such a simple task (such as the provider having deprecated configuration options in the my.cnf file causing MySQL to not startup correctly, and having to import a ridiculously large database from Drupal causing all sorts of problems).

But the most recent problem I've run into is the site simply not executing and just returning an Error 500. PHP is installed, but I can't find the PHP5_Module in the Apache Modules, instead there is "suphp_module" which is a shared module. PHP Error Reporting is switched on, as is error reporting in the .htdocs file.

If I add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` to the mime type it just causes the PHP files to download upon being loaded.

I'm honestly running out of ideas here, is it because php is not correctly installed, do I have to reinstall php5?

EDIT: Added the Apache Logs, not sure if the first line has anything to do with it however.

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/creative/public_html/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

Comment: What do your logs say? also WHM has EasyApache which will make your life very easy if you do need to recompile Apache and PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added those to begin with. Added now.

Comment: You may have added the files with your root account so the files have the owner as `root` you don't need to recompile apache or php just change the group/user of the scripts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711085/uid-of-script-home-public-html-index-php-is-smaller-than-min-uid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the php to other owner and group as it is probably assigned to `root:root` that isn't secure, so the system prevent the execution

You can assign the webserver user and group that is likely to be `apache` if you're running `httpd`

Comment: So, I have to have the scripts owned by the same user running Apache? Can I put a different user in the same group, will the files then execute?