# 500 Internal Server Error when accessing domain/foldername

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am getting the 500 Internal Server Error on my website.
Full message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@subxchange.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at subxchange.com Port 443
```

Image: http://i.gyazo.com/31e237bca4593dc71b0923ba9c044ae1.png

I am getting the message when trying to access my admin panel such as domain.com/admin-panel
I can however access the frontend just fine such as domain.com.

I have checked the permissions and folders are set to 755 while files are set to 644.

This is the error log:

```
[Sat Jun 20 14:57:59.954476 2015] [:error] [pid 7920] [client 213.114.166.90:35286] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/subxchange/public_html/admin-panel/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
[Sat Jun 20 14:56:09.703965 2015] [:error] [pid 7564] [client 213.114.166.90:35213] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/subxchange/public_html/admin-panel/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
[Sat Jun 20 14:56:09.398852 2015] [:error] [pid 7910] [client 213.114.166.90:35198] SoftException in Application.cpp:357: UID of script "/home/subxchange/public_html/admin-panel/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
....
```

Does someone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711085/uid-of-script-home-public-html-index-php-is-smaller-than-min-uid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permissions issue, you need to set correct user and group ownership in addition to rwx:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/subxchange/public_html
```

And make sure correct properties for `public_html` are set:

```
chmod 755 -R /home/subxchange/public_html
```

Comment: I tried with the following: `chown -R nobody:nobody /home/subxchange/public_html/admin-panel/` but nothing really happened, am I supposed to enter some kind of password?

Comment: Check what user runs PHP server process. Run `ls -l` in `home/subxchange/public_html`. Try running command in answer on `public_html` not on `admin-panel`.