# Android http post with params error code 500

Tags: php, android, http-post

I want add the new supports data via http post. Im getting an error response code is 500. I check code and php files i cant see any problem. And I dont complete code how i can get result after solve 500 error.

**NewSupport.java**

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("myurl/db_newSupport.php");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .appendQueryParameter("uniq",  "UNIQ")
            .appendQueryParameter("data",  "DATA")
            .appendQueryParameter("date",  "DATE");
    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(query);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line="";

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**db_newSupport.php**

```
$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['uniq']) && isset($_POST['data']) && isset($_POST['date'])) {

    $uniq  = $_POST['uniq'];
    $data  = $_POST['data'];
    $date  = $_POST['date'];

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db    = new DB_CONNECT();
    $result= mysql_query("INSERT INTO new(uniq, data, date) VALUES('$uniq', '$data', '$date')");

    if ($result) {
        $response["code"]  = 1;
        $response["info"]  = "successfully";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["code"]  = 0;
        $response["info"]  = "error";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["code"] = 99;
    $response["info"] = "error";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the php tag in your db_newSupport.php file missing or you didn't pasted it here?

Comment: I was paste it but didnt show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a server-side problem.

1. Enable PHP-errors : https://stackoverflow.com/a/845025/1979882
2. Change POST method into GET in order to check the result is any browser to simplify debuggind.

3.Write resultant log here.

Look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711595/1979882

and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717056/1979882

in brief, execute this `chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/`

Comment: While crash I have to see the logs in the response of HTTP body.

Comment: I find logs: Premature end of script headers: db_newSupport.php and SoftException in Application.cpp:350: UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/db_newSupport.php" is smaller than min_uid

Comment: execute this: chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache/htdocs/ and restart php

Comment: It doesnt work. Last logs: SoftException in Application.cpp:350: UID of script "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/db_newSupport.php" is smaller than min_uid
Premature end of script headers: db_newSupport.php

Comment: yes at first  httpd restart after reboot but it doesnt work :( I show php file manager file permissions; htdocs = perm 755 group 0 owner 0 and php files = perm 755 group 0 owner 0

Comment: Works after change owner group name.(chown XX:XX db_newSupport.php) Thank you for helps :)

Comment: @kibAr , approve the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Ok, I forgot :)

Comment: Have a nice coding;)

Answer (score 1):

**500** response code means server side crash. You should look at server logs for crash details.

Look at [list of http status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0):

500 means internal server error.

Thing you are giving the relative path of your URL. Try giving the absolute path like "http://< your domain name>/db_newSupport.php".